# How to sum up combined string has serval numbers in a pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, split, sum

I have a string contains comma delimited int values, such as x = "1,2,3,4,5,6"
, how to calculate the sum of x contained values?

I tried:

```
values = x.split(",").map(lambda a:int(a))
sum(values)
```

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'map'

Actually, I have a pandas DataFrame have such data format:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[100,101,201],
                   'prices_a':['1,2,3','4,5,6','7,8,9'],
                   'prices_b':['1,2,3','2,6,6','3,5,8']})
```

so it would be:

```
   id     prices_a prices_b
0  100    1,2,3    1,2,3
1  101    4,5,6    2,6,6
2  201    7,8,9    3,5,8
```

I would add a new column diff to compare `prices_a` & `prices_b,` if they are same, then `df['diff'] = 'match'`, otherwise, `df['diff'] = sum(prices_a values) - sum(prices_b b values)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), for `sum`s columns use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html), [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) with `sum` per rows (`axis=1`):

```
a = df['prices_a'].str.split(',', expand=True).astype(float).sum(axis=1)
b = df['prices_b'].str.split(',', expand=True).astype(float).sum(axis=1)

print (a)
0     6.0
1    15.0
2    24.0
dtype: float64

print (b)
0     6.0
1    14.0
2    16.0
dtype: float64

df['df'] =  np.where(df['prices_a'] == df['prices_b'], 'match', a - b)
print (df)
    id prices_a prices_b     df
0  100    1,2,3    1,2,3  match
1  101    4,5,6    2,6,6    1.0
2  201    7,8,9    3,5,8    8.0
```

But better is not mixed strings with numeric.

So then is possible use e.g `NaN`s instead `match`:

```
df['diff'] =  np.where(df['prices_a'] == df['prices_b'], np.nan, a - b)
print (df)
    id prices_a prices_b  diff
0  100    1,2,3    1,2,3   NaN
1  101    4,5,6    2,6,6   1.0
2  201    7,8,9    3,5,8   8.0
```

Comment: Thanks very much. BTW, I understand your suggestion regarding using NaN.  The questions is simplified, in production environment, will make it more elegant as suggested.